# Underscore's _.without not excluding substring in the following array?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I wanted to turn this:

```
[ 'para', 'this is a paragraph']
```

into this (picking the first tree words of the second string of the array, then put them inside a nested array with an additional `em`).

```
[ 'para', [ 'em', 'this is a' ], 'paragraph' ]
```

So I tried the following:

```
var para = tree[1]

var firstTreeItems = para[1].split(' ', 3).join(' ')
para[1] = _.without(para[1].split(' '), firstTreeItems.split(' ')).join(' ')
para.splice(1, 0, ['em', res])

console.log(para)
```

But it didn't work, `_.without` isn't excluding `this is a` in the last part of the array:

```
[ 'para', [ 'em', 'this is a' ], 'this is a paragraph' ]
```

What I'm a doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any rules to pick the strings? In this case, why `this is a` is picked?

Comment: Then why `para` is excluded?

Comment: @thefourtheye OK, I updated the question. Yes, I'm not working with `'para'` so I use `para[1]` to just grab the second string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change two lines to:

```
var firstTreeItems = para[1].split(' ', 3)
para[1] = _.without(para[1].split(' '), firstTreeItems[0], firstTreeItems[1], firstTreeItems[2]).join(' ')
```

`_.without` is not looking to remove the elements of the `firstTreeItems` array you provided, it is looking to remove the array itself, and not finding it.

First I'm leaving `firstTreeItems` as an array so I can access each element individually. Then I'm giving each undesired element to `_.without` to remove from our temporary `para[1].split(' ')` array.

Comment: Thanks. I realized I could shorten the code by doing: `_.difference(para[1].split(' '), firstTreeItems).join(' ')`